# Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall

Tags: c

I'm very unexperienced in programming and were trying to create a code for a homework to generate 6 random numbers (like in a dice) in two groups of three, and compare them, lower with lower, higher with higher, etc., and register the results, much like "war" game, but in a great number of plays.
So, i ended up with the following code:

```
rodadas = 3;

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    ataque_vitorias=0;

    ataque[1] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    ataque[2] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    ataque[3] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    defesa[1] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    defesa[2] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    defesa[3] = rand() % 6 + 1;

    j=0;
    k=0;
    for (j=0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
    {
        for (k=0 ; k < 2 ; k++)
        {
            if (ataque[k+1] < ataque[k])
            {
                t = ataque[k];
                ataque[k] = ataque[k + 1];
                ataque[k + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    j=0;
    k=0;
    for (j=0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
    {
        for (k=0 ; k < 2 ; k++)
        {
            if (defesa[k+1] < defesa[k])
            {
                t = defesa[k];
                defesa[k] = defesa[k + 1];
                defesa[k + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ataque[1] > defesa[1])
        ataque_vitorias++;
    if (ataque[2] > defesa[2])
        ataque_vitorias++;
    if (ataque[3] > defesa[3])
        ataque_vitorias++;

    if (ataque_vitorias == 0) total_0++;
    if (ataque_vitorias == 1) total_1++;
    if (ataque_vitorias == 2) total_2++;
    if (ataque_vitorias == 3) total_3++;
}

printf("total_0: %d\n", total_0);
printf("total_1: %d\n", total_1);
printf("total_2: %d\n", total_2);
printf("total_3: %d\n", total_3);

return 0;
```

And defined all the variables ind the main void. The problem is when i try to run it, i keep getting the error:

> Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall

I don't have any idea of how to fix it so the code can run.
Sorry for the bad english (i'm not native) and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This looks like C to me and not C#.  C arrays start at 0, not 1.  The error message is pretty poor in this case, but I think you are indexing outside the bounds of your array and getting undefined behavior.  Fix your indexing issues and I bet you fix this SYS_socketcall error.

Comment: Show the declarations of `ataque` and `defesa`. If it's `int ataque[3]` then @MFisherKDX is correct, you have UB and random errors like this are likely.

Comment: The declarations:
int rodadas;
    int ataque_vitorias=0;
    int total_0=0;
    int total_1=0;
    int total_2=0;
    int total_3=0;
    int i=0;
    int c=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int t=0;
    int ataque[3]={ 0, 0, 0};
    int defesa[3]={ 0, 0, 0};
I'm trying to fix like @MFisherKDX said and see if it works!

Comment: It worked! Thank you both!